# How to take controller over UrlPathHelper#getOriginatingRequestUri

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redirect

I am working with a legacy website that use Spring MVC 3.1 and I have a [HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) that intercept any request to `www.mysite.com/` and send redirect to `www.mysite.com/mybasepath/`.

```
public class MyRedirectInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    String myContextPath = "www.mysite.com";
    if (isRequestToRootUrl(request)) {
        String redirectUrl = myContextPath + "/mybasepath/";
        response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now, the controller that handle request to `www.mysite.com/mybasepath/` has a code that internally use Spring's [UrlPathHelper#getOriginatingRequestUri](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/util/UrlPathHelper.html).

<strike>The problem is this controller assume that the result of `UrlPathHelper#getOriginatingRequestUri` must be of the form `"/mybasepath/*"`. But because I had the `"/"` redirected to `"/mybasepath/"` by using `response.sendRedirect(...)`, the result of `UrlPathHelper#getOriginatingRequestUri` will be just `"/"`, which will cause an error.</strike>

**So I am seeking a way to modify `MyRedirectInterceptor` so that the result of `UrlPathHelper#getOriginatingRequestUri` after the redirection be `"/mybasepath/"` instead.**

**Edit**

It's my misunderstanding that the `UrlPathHelper#getOriginatingRequestUri` returns the path before the redirection. Actually it doesn't. It returns the correct "/mybasepath/". My mistake was caused by another point in the code.

Answer (score 1):

getRequestUri ist implemented like this.

```
187 public String More ...getRequestUri(HttpServletRequest request) {
188     String uri = (String) request.getAttribute(WebUtils.INCLUDE_REQUEST_URI_ATTRIBUTE);
189     if (uri == null) {
190         uri = request.getRequestURI();
191     }
192     return decodeAndCleanUriString(request, uri);
193 }
```

my be thw follwing helps

```
request.setAttribute(WebUtils.INCLUDE_REQUEST_URI_ATTRIBUTE, "my value")
```